# Пробелы в textarea при считывании с БД

Tags: php, html, mysql, textarea

При считывании информации с БД в textarea выводит отступы в начало строки.

[image: Результат выполнения кода]

```
<?php  function articles_edit($link, $id, $title, $date, $content){
    $title = trim($title);
    $content = trim($content);
    $date = trim($date);
    $id = (int)$id;

    if($title == '')
        return false;

    $sql = "UPDATE articles SET title='%s', content='%s', date='%s' where id='%d'";

    $query = sprintf($sql, mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $title),
                            mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $content),
                            mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $date),
                            $id);

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    if (!$result)
        die(mysqli_error($link));

    return mysqli_affected_rows($link); } ?>

    <textarea class="form-item" name="content" required>
         <?=$article['content']?> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я не хочу Вас расстраивать, но:

```html
<textarea class="form-item" name="content" required>
             Текст </textarea>

<textarea class="form-item" name="content" required>

             Текст </textarea>

<textarea class="form-item" name="content" required>Текст</textarea>
```

Comment: :D Однако, упущенный момент

Comment: Зоркий глаз, я даже не брал в расчет такую банальщину

Answer (score 0):

Так обрежь лишние отступы.
`<?php echo trim($article['content']); ?>`

Comment: Вопрос более интересен, почему в БД попадает строка с пробелами. Хотя перед вставкой обрезаются все пробелы

Comment: Это уже совсем другой вопрос. Судя по коду, пробелов не должно быть. Чтоб убедиться можно вывести текст самого запроса. Далее проверить саму колонку в базе данных. А потом проверить то, как эти данные извлекаются из базы, и что с ними делается. И чтоб добить, проверить код символа, который скрывается под видом пробела.

Comment: trim я уже использую в коде php, где идет считывание с БД. Пробовал вставлять его в самую textarea результата 0. І что интересного я еще заметил, что даже когда использую textarea просто чтоб набрать в нем текст, отступ там уже присутствует. А когда отправляю через нее данные, то в БД пробела уже нет. Вот такой вот нонсенс.

Comment: Да вон выше уже указали на косяк, который и я просмотрел. В коде textarea уже есть те самые пробелы.

Comment: Большое спасибо банальная ошибка)